# Chart.js is not working on my Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chart.js

The console is clear and I am using latest CDN from cdnjs and also the chartjs code is from their official documentation. Even though the chart is not loading. My browser is google chrome.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");
    var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are using Chart.js v1 library with Chart.js v2 syntax. Here's your working fiddle with Chart.js v2 library https://jsfiddle.net/dnts7t7a/

Comment: @ManishYadav yeah, thank you, I replaced the CDN and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old version of chart.js

Replace your `script` tag with this and your sample works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
```

I can't get the SO snippets to work, but here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xekp0mzz/